# Can't make app design only for iPhone 5 and 4 in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I don't wanna make my app's design compatible for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus, I just wanna scale the 4 inch version that I use for the older retina screen.

In my other app it was pretty easy because I created it in Xcode 5. But now the problem is that I don't know how can I achieve this in Xcode 6. The app isn't universal project and I turned off the size classes in storyboard, but it's still not what I want. It doesn't scales the 4 inch version, it display everything "correctly".

I know it can happen if you use the Storyboard or LaunchScreen.xib as launch images, but actually I'm using an asset catalog. Another issue is at the launch images (asset catalog) there are icons for the Retina HD 5.5 and 4.7. I don't really understand this, because these devices should use the LaunchScreen.xib as a launch screen.

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me how can I solve this problem without installing Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the General tab in Target Settings, you have to do two things.

- Launch Images Source : Just click "Use Asset Catalog"
- Launch Screen File: Make this area empty

That should do it.

Comment: I did the same, at the launch images there are still icons for the 4.7 and 5.5 Retina screen. Doesn't matter when I make the launch screen file field empty.

Comment: In the attributes inspector tab you should uncheck the iOS 8.0 and later option.

Comment: Actually I'm using the iOS 7 or later option, and doesn't help.

Comment: That's totally what I wanted. Thank you very much for your efforts.